# Angular2 ng2-smart-table sorting

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

In **ng2-smart-table** of *angular* 2 sorting functionality is *case sensitive*. Are there any options to make sorting table data as *case insensitive*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **You can provide your custom sorting function as the 4th argument in the sort() method.**

**Example:**

```
let COMPARE_INSENSITIVE = (direction: any, a: any, b: any) => {
  // Converting strings to lowercase
  let first = typeof a === 'string' ? a.toLowerCase() : a;
  let second = typeof b === 'string' ? b.toLowerCase() : b;

  if (first < second) {
     return -1 * direction;
  }
  if (first > second) {
    return direction;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

**ng2-smart-table** uses the following default COMPARE function:

```
export class LocalSorter {

  protected static COMPARE = (direction: any, a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a < b) {
     return -1 * direction;
    }
    if (a > b) {
      return direction;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  static sort(data: Array<any>, field: string, direction: string, customCompare?: Function): Array<any> {

    const dir: number = (direction === 'asc') ? 1 : -1;
    const compare: Function = customCompare ? customCompare : this.COMPARE;

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      return compare.call(null, dir, a[field], b[field]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: where to insert this code? is this custom function?

Comment: As Lumix wrote, you can provide the attribute compareFunction in table configuration: [Documentation with all table configuration properties](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

Comment: Is there an error? Can you please provide code or more details?

Comment: organization_name: {
        title: 'Organization Name',
                 //I added that code here
        filter:true,
        sort:true,
        editable:true,
        addable:true,
        width: '25%',

      },

Comment: The code from Lumix's answer? In that case try changing **compareFunction(** to **compareFunction: (** . If it still doesn't work, please edit your question with the current code and error message

Comment: it is still not wrkng  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158599/discussion-between-wojciech-k-and-revathi-sekar).

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to throw out if you implement this to make sure you add a : after compareFunction. As shown below...

```
columns: {
    group_name: {
        title: 'Groupname',
        compareFunction:(direction: any, a: any, b: any) => {
            // Converting strings to lowercase
            let first = typeof a === 'string' ? a.toLowerCase() : a;
            let second = typeof b === 'string' ? b.toLowerCase() : b;

            if (first < second) {
                return -1 * direction;
            }
            if (first > second) {
                return direction;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```